# Adding keyboard shortcuts to execute Chrome extension

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I have created a chrome extension which I'd like to cause execution using a keyboard shortcut.

Snippet:

```
"suggested_key": {
  "default": "Ctrl+Shift+F"
```

I've tried different combinations such as "Ctrl+Shift+A", "Ctrl+Shift+D", "Alt+X" and "Space+B"

None of these seems to work. Am I spelling out Alt or Space wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggested key from your `manifest` file works only if there is no other action bound to the same keyboard shortcut.

From [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands):

> The user is free to designate any shortcut as global using the UI in
>   chrome://extensions \ Keyboard Shortcuts, but the extension developer
>   is limited to specifying only Ctrl+Shift+[0..9] as global shortcuts.
>   This is to minimize the risk of overriding shortcuts in other
>   applications since if, for example, Alt+P were to be allowed as
>   global, the printing shortcut might not work in other applications.

So, `Ctrl+Shift+F` it's a setting in a `View` menu of the Chrome. You need to override it manually or find another shortcut.

Also, you need to re-install your extension to activating a new shortcut from the manifest.

Comment: Your last sentence proved fruitful. I was just running it again but it didn't recognise the new shortcut. Added it again and it worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you assign a default, that means that users can never ***unset*** that shortcut. This is likely an [issue with Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1275357).